# One image is displayed and one is not in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have 2 images in html, one is shown, but the second one is not, I have tried to put another different image in the second one but it is still not shown. Both are in the same path.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img id="borderIcono" th:src="@{/images/icono_prueba.png}" width="60" height="60" alt=""/></a>
<button ng-click="cargando = true" ng-disabled="cargando">
    <img th:src="@{/images/redo.png}" class="redoBoton"/>
</button>
```

I have also tried to put the second image outside the button and without the class attribute, but it is still not displayed. So the css is not the problem.
I have tried to interchange them and the first one is seen where the second one is but the second one is still not seen in the place of the first one.
In inspect the browser tells me that the image could not be loaded.
I know that both images are in the same folder, so both should be accessible.

[image]

Comment: Please show the rendered html in your question, too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug, the server was not putting the image inside the compiled application, that is, I put the file in the source folder, but when I run it, it reads whatever is in the target folder.